# Are there any simple pairwise comparison tests suitable for comparing emotions?

Tags: statistical-significance, paired-data, psychometrics

So, I'm pretty new to using statistics in a research context. I am currently writing my thesis in didactics of mathematics. In my study, a group of $10$ students are to solve two different mathematical problems (at two different occasions) and afterwards fill in a self-report questionnaire asking them to rate *how often* they felt a specific emotion during the problemsolving. This is done via a $5$-point likert scale from *never* to *very often*. The following emotions are to be rated:

1. Liked it
2. Found it beautiful
3. Felt excited
4. Amused me
5. Felt pleasure
6. Felt surprised
7. Felt lost
8. Made me curious
9. Sparked my interest
10. Felt intelectually challenged
11. Felt a sudden insight
12. Found it ugly
13. Felt bored
14. Felt confused
15. Felt frustrated
16. Felt anxious
17. Felt sad

One student ($S_{1}$) in an informal pilot test filled in the following scores for the first *applied* mathematical problem: $5, 5, 5, 4, 2, 1, 5, 5, 2, 3, 1, 5, 2, 1, 1, 1$.

And for the other *pure* mathematical problem: $3, 2, 3, 3, 3, 1, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 4, 4, 3, 1$.

So, how can I do some simple (adequate in a research context) comparison test on these two different scores? Just by eye-balling the scores above it seems rather obvious that $S_{1}$ gives on average higher scores on the applied mathematical problem. And if I have, say $10$ different students what type of test would then be adequate to use?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A crude way to do it is to compare averages. For example: let $Y_{ipq}$ be subject $i$’s Likert response on problem $p$ to question $q$, and $X_p$ be 1 if $p$ is applied and 0 if it is pure. Regress $Y_{ipq}$ on $X_p$. The coefficient on $X_p$ is the average Likert response difference for applied problems.

Comment: Thanks. Could you give a more speicifc example. I dont really understand what it means to "regress $Y_{ipq}$ on $X_{p}$. I understand that you mean some regression analysis but dont understand exactly how.

Comment: I assumed that you were familiar with regression analysis in which case this would be an intuitive way of thinking about the problem. But what I am describing is the same as calculating the average responses for applied maths problems, for pure maths problems, and subtracting the first average from the second. However, somebody who is trained in psychometrics should be able to give you a better suggestion.